# How to get the data from controller to view on refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static string selection = String.Empty;
    dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
    public ActionResult Post(string Name)
    {
        selection = Name;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SegmentRepository segment = new SegmentRepository();
        mymodel.listofSegments = segment.GetSegmentation();
        DynamicRepository dynamic = new DynamicRepository();
        mymodel.listofDynamic = dynamic.GetDynamicContent(selection); //After selecting the segmentation in the view it returns the required dynamic content in mymodel.listofDynamic  but does not display it in the view.
        return View(mymodel);

    }
```

After selecting the segmentation in the view it returns the required dynamic content in mymodel.listofDynamic  but does not display it in the view.

View :

```
//Ajax 
<script>
function seg() {
    var employment = document.getElementById("Employment").value;
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
        url: '@Url.Action("Post","Home")', // Controller/View
        data: { //Passing data
            Name: employment //Reading text box values using Jquery
        }
    }
    )
}
```

```
<tr>
                <td height="100">
                    <label>220</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select id="Employment">
                           <option>---Select---</option>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.listofSegments)
                        {      
                            <option name="selectedSegment" value="@item">@item</option>
                        }
                       </select>
                         <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" onclick="seg()">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="Dynamic">
                        <option>---Select---</option>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.listofDynamic)
                        {
                            <option name="selectedDynamic" value="@item">@item</option>
                        }// I need the data to get listed here
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="Submit1">
            </tr>
```

Need the ActionResult Index to run again so the data in listofDynamic gets printed in the View.

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading your required div on 'success' method of ajax. Here you are returning the response (plain HTML as View here) and not binding it anywhere.

ajax call is asynchronous, it will not reload the entire view.

Find the code below

```
$.ajax( 


       {
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            success: function (returnData,success)
            {

                $("#sampleDiv").html(returnData);

            }

        }
    );
```